# How do you clean the Seaside URLs?

Tags: seaside

So, if you download a fresh Seaside image and run WAKom startOn: 80, then your fresh seaside respons on localhost/seaside/

This /seaside-folder annoys me, as I want to publish on [seasidehosting](http://www.seasidehosting.st).

So! How do I remove this part of the URL?

I want my app to be reachable under myapp.seasidehosting.st

Without any path in the name of the URL.

niko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply execute:

```
WADispatcher default setName: ''
```

Comment: Umm, I am confused.  When I do this, my libraries are not included anymore. I made my special library, and it just quits being found. how strange! on localhost things work great, but on seasidehosting not so much. why oh why?

Answer (score 1):

Aha! I found it in the seasidehosting faq. There it states:

> Go to the Seaside configuration page and select your preferred application as default entry point. Set the base-path of your application to "/". Note that this only works with recent versions of Seaside.

Ok, that should be manageable.

*Edit*: But it doesn't quite work. How do you set the base path? Still working on that ...

Comment: Point your browser to localhost/seaside/config, then click edit near your application. PS: This is more a problem with how Seaside plugs into the HTTP server, rather than with Seaside per se.